# Generate PDF file from HTML string in asp.net with vb

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate PDF file from HTML string and that PDF file I have to attach in mail using asp.net. I try ghtmldoc.exe, it will generate corrupted pdf file.

I also use iTextsharp. It generate PDF without format though I don't use CSS in that HTML page. Only data in html file is converted in PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found Winnovative HTML to PDF converter very useful for doing things like this:

http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx

You can either specify a URL to convert to PDF, or specify a HTML string to convert to PDF instead.

An open source solution, would be iTextSharp:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is good but I want free source not licensed.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to pdf is really made simple by telerik. check this [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx). Telerik has a good look too. so if you are not late to change over to telerik, i suggest do that.