# Export multiple Rad Grids to single PDF

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am using telerik controls on my aspx page. I have around 7 Rad Grids(similar to GridView) on my page. Now, telerik has one step export to pdf options for rad grid's. But this is for exporting individual rad grid's. I want to export the data in all rad grid's to 1 pdf file. Telerik has solution for this mentioned on their support page. But it asks to include 1 rad grid that encapsulates these 7 radgrids and then export that single radgrid to pdf.

But all of my 7 rad grids have different data sources. When i wrap my rad grids into one single rad grid, i cannot access the inner radgrids in c#.

Can someone suggest some solutions that I can try?

Thankyou,
Ghanshyam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610845/generate-pdf-file-from-html-string-in-asp-net-with-vb) (about PDF export). Maybe the product mentioned in one of the answers might help you:

http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx